# Accesing 2d arrays from Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I have an 2d array in which data about NPCs are stored:

```
// id is just NPC number
NPC[id][x] = ; // here is stored the x coordinate
NPC[id][y] = ; // here is stored the y coordinate
```

There are also other data about NPCs stored in NPC matrix and I want to access them, but I don't know the id of NPC I want to change. I only know his x and y coordinates. How would I find out his id?

P.S. I'm a noob and I know that this way of managing NPCs is lame and bad programming, but its too late to change it now.

Comment: side-note: there's no such thing as a 2d array in javascript (or any loosely typed language). it's just an array that happens to contain an array at every indice.

Comment: The question is totally unclear. What are `x` and `y`? Are they properties? So you have `NPC[id]["x"] = 4;` where `4` is the x of the character? Otherwise if they are "number", are they the actual coordinate? There what is stored in "x"? The same value? `NPC[id][4] = 4` ? Please explain the scenario better. Also, keep in mind that if you want to retrieve a character based on x/y coords, it's better if you have an array like: `maps[x][y] = idNPC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the external indice, you'd have to loop through every element in the array and compare the values of their x/y coordinates to your given coordinates, then return the ID when you find a match, or some sentinel value if you reach the end without finding a match.